# Matrix structure; maybe you can see something I can't...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am attempting to find a 'smarter' way to solve a matrix, in the form $Ax=B$, where

$B_{i}=F_i*N$

$A_{i,j}=-F_i/K_{j,i}$

where $N$ is constant, $K$ is a constant matrix, and $F$ is a vector of;

$F_i=Y_i/K_{i,i}$

where $Y$ is a vector constant.

I'm not hugely mathematical, and my linear algebra skills could be put on the back of a napkin, but seeing this kind of repetition indicates to me that there must be a shortcut for this.

Does anyone have any insights?

Comment: You can cancel the $F_i$'s.

Comment: I was thinking more about the structure of the resultant matrix but yeah, I wanted a second opinion on that too (I have no real understanding of the weirdnesses of linalg...)

Comment: Think of it as a system of equations. For each $i$ you have an equation of the form $\sum_j A_{ij} x_i = B_i$. In your case, this is $\sum_j -F_i/K_{ji} = NF_i$, so you can cancel the $F_i$'s. Otherwise it's almost completely arbitrary (other than the fact that $-1/K_{ji}$ cannot be zero).

Comment: You can also cancel the $N$ if you want. Solve if for RHS which is constant $1$, then multiply the result by $N$.

Comment: There's a typo above; it should read $\sum_j A_{ij} x_j = B_i$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).

Answer (score 1):

Let's write your system of equations in full. For each $i$, you have an equation
$$
\sum_j (-F_i/K_{ij}) x_j = F_i N.
$$
As you can see, you can cancel the $F_i$ (assuming for simplicity that they are non-zero):
$$
\sum_j (-1/K_{ij}) x_j = N.
$$
Other than that, the matrix $A$ is rather arbitrary (aside for having no non-zero entries).

Another simplification is to get rid of $N$: you can solve the system for $N = 1$, then multiply the solution by $N$.